# HP 5120 vlan not working

Tags: hp, switch, vlan

So I have this odd issue with our HP 5120 switches. The VLANs will not pass traffic unless a interface with a IP is assigned to the VLAN. Problem is there is a limit of 8 VLAN interfaces that are allowed on these switches, and we have 11 VLANs we need all to be working...

When I say "pass traffic" I mean assign a VLAN without a interface on port 1 and 2. Plug something in on both ports and assign the VLAN(tagged) on each device, try to ping each other and nothing happens. Add a VLAN interface to that same VLAN with a IP and now they can ping each other.

Has anyone else seen this before? Is there a config screw up somewhere?

I asked this same question over in [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/802907/hp-5120-vlan-not-working) before I realized that it would be a better fit if asked here.

Comment: By "pass traffic", do you mean inter-vlan routing?

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: I'm sorry. It's not quite clear. Can you post the configuration? Do you want untagged packets from your device, or do you actually intend to define the vlan on the devices?

Comment: The ports have the vlan marked as tagged, and the devices plugged into each port are defining the tagged vlans. How can I post the config? Is there a way to add files to comments?

Comment: How do I share the config?